# WebViewCompatible Navigate With Headers

Tags: .net, webbrowser-control, windows-community-toolkit

None of the Navigate methods on Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebViewCompatible take PostData arguments.

https://github.com/windows-toolkit/Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32/issues/23 suggests casting the WebViewCompatible's View property to a Forms.WebBrowser.  I am unable to get that cast to work.

```
WebBrowser ie = webViewCompatible1 as WebBrowser;
ie.Navigate(url, null, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(credentialstr), "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Error   CS0039  Cannot convert type 'Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebViewCompatible' to 'System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion

Answer (score 0):

This cast only works if you are using Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.Controls.WebView, I was using Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView.  I do not know if this is documented anywhere.